# Filter XML results on AJAX get request

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and I'm trying to put together an example of pulling filterable information from an XML document to a webpage. So far I'm trying to create an array with these filtered XML items, then pull items from the array onto the page.

My XML document is very simple, and all I want to do is show the items where the "type" is 100. Is it best practice to do this filtering server side or is it okay to filter during/after the request? Does anyone know why this script isn't working and/or if there's a more efficient method?

Here is my XML:

```
<items>
    <item id="1">
        <type>100</type>
    <item>
    <item id="2">
        <type>101</type>
    <item>
    <item id="3">
        <type>100</type>
    <item>
    <item id="4">
        <type>102</type>
    <item>
</items>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var array = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "text.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find("item").each(function(){
                if( x == $(this).find("type") == "100"){
                    $(this).push(array);
                }
            });   
    });

    $.each(array, function() {
        $(body).append("<p>" + $(this).attr("id") + "</p>" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "text.xml",
        success: function(xml){
          var items = $(xml).find("item").filter(function(){
              return $('type', this).text() == '100';
          });
          items.each(function(index, item){
              $('body').append("<p>" + $(item).attr("id") + "</p>" );
          });
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N7PxSNJt3VkjecTmWQep?p=preview)

***Note:*** There is a problem in your xml, the closing tag for `item` is not proper, it should be `</item>`

Comment: thank you! This is awesome, will this return items with a type of "1001" as well as it contains '100' somewhere or is contains an equivalent of say "equal to"? Thanks again!

Comment: @mmmoustache in that case you can write a custom filter